# link ITK header files in C++ project

Tags: c++, itk

I am sorry if my problem is trivial, but I tried many solutions and nothing works out. I am trying to run a simple HelloWorld program, and make an inclusion of header file of `ITK: itkImage.h`.

Running `cmake ../src` to build the Makefile is okay.
But running `make all` gives this error: `/src/HelloWorldTwo.cpp:10:22: fatal error: itkImage.h: No such file or directory
 #include "itkImage.h"`

Find below my `CMakeLists.txt` file and `HelloWorldTwo.cpp`
What I am missing here? I tried to run make command from Eclipse and from command window, but no success. I am sure the `ITK_DIR` contains `ITKConfig.cmake`, that's why `cmake` is okay!

Thank you!

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(HelloWorldTwo)
# Find ITK.
set(ITK_DIR "/home/usr/itk/lib/cmake/ITK-4.13")
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
add_executable(HelloWorldTwo HelloWorldTwo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorldTwo ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

HelloWorldTwo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "itkImage.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Debugging the variables in CMakeLists.txt:

-- ITK_DIR: /home/usr/itk/lib/cmake/ITK-4.13

-- ITK_LIBRARIES: itkdouble-conversionitksysitkvnl_algoitkvnlitkv3p_netlibitknetlibitkvclITKCommonitkNetlibSlatecITKStatisticsITKTransformITKLabelMapITKMeshitkzlibITKMetaIOITKSpatialObjectsITKPathITKQuadEdgeMeshITKIOImageBaseITKOptimizersITKPolynomialsITKBiasCorrectionITKBioCellITKDICOMParserITKEXPATITKIOXMLITKIOSpatialObjectsITKFEMgdcmDICTgdcmMSFFITKznzITKniftiioITKgiftiiohdf5_cpp-statichdf5-staticITKIOBMPITKIOBioRadITKIOBrukerITKIOCSVITKIOGDCMITKIOIPLITKIOGEITKIOGIPLITKIOHDF5itkjpegITKIOJPEGitktiffITKIOTIFFITKIOLSMitkminc2ITKIOMINCITKIOMRCITKIOMeshITKIOMetaITKIONIFTIITKNrrdIOITKIONRRDitkpngITKIOPNGITKIOSiemensITKIOStimulateITKTransformFactoryITKIOTransformBaseITKIOTransformHDF5ITKIOTransformInsightLegacyITKIOTransformMatlabITKIOVTKITKKLMRegionGrowingitklbfgsITKOptimizersv4itkopenjpegITKVTKITKWatershedsITKReviewITKVideoCoreITKVideoIOITKVtkGlue

Comment: Have you tried 'debugging' it by printing your variables, especially `ITK_LIBRARIES`, as messages?

Comment: I have edited the post. I think it should be correct, because I can see `ITKIOImageBase` in the list of libraries. What do you think?

Comment: Just to make sure: did you try `#include <itkImage.h>` ?

Comment: @mahesh That should not make a difference, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594/5909613

Comment: @matlabuser It looks funny to me. Is this really one long string without spaces or anything?

Comment: @JeromeReinländer : Yes. You are right. I wasn't thinking I guess :-).

Answer (score 0):

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)` - you might want to update this to 2.8.12 at least, as that is the minimum required version for [ITK 4.13](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v4.13.0/CMakeLists.txt#L1). And newer being better, try setting it to 3.10.2 (or whichever CMake version you have). Also, `ITK_LIBRARIES` should be semicolon-separated list, not merged like that. `message(STATUS "ITK_LIBRARIES: ${ITK_LIBRARIES}")` should produce something like:

`ITK_LIBRARIES: itkdouble-conversion;itksys;itkvnl_algo;itkvnl;itkv3p_netlib;itknetlib;itkvcl;ITKCommon;itkNetlibSlatec;ITKStatistics;ITKTransform;ITKMesh;itkzlib;ITKMetaIO;ITKSpatialObjects;ITKPath;ITKEXPAT;ITKznz;ITKniftiio;ITKgiftiio;ITKIOImageBase;ITKIOMesh;IOSTL;ITKLabelMap;ITKQuadEdgeMesh;ITKOptimizers;ITKPolynomials;ITKBiasCorrection;ITKBioCell;ITKDICOMParser;ITKIOXML;ITKIOSpatialObjects;ITKFEM;gdcmDICT;gdcmMSFF;hdf5_cpp-static;hdf5-static;ITKIOBMP;ITKIOBioRad;ITKIOCSV;ITKIOGDCM;ITKIOIPL;ITKIOGE;ITKIOGIPL;ITKIOHDF5;itkjpeg;ITKIOJPEG;itktiff;ITKIOTIFF;ITKIOLSM;ITKIOMRC;ITKIOMeta;ITKIONIFTI;ITKNrrdIO;ITKIONRRD;itkpng;ITKIOPNG;ITKIOSiemens;ITKIOStimulate;ITKTransformFactory;ITKIOTransformBase;ITKIOTransformHDF5;ITKIOTransformInsightLegacy;ITKIOTransformMatlab;ITKIOVTK;ITKKLMRegionGrowing;ITKOptimizersv4;itkopenjpeg;ITKVTK;ITKWatersheds;ITKReview;ITKVideoCore;ITKVideoIO;ITKVtkGlue`.

Comment: I have updated cmake version, but it didn't changed the output. About the missed semicolon: I have no idea why it is like that. Do you have any guess? Or what I should check about it?